# Why am I losing my DefaultRequestHeaders with DelegatingHandler?

Tags: c#, .net-core, request-headers, polly, httpclientfactory

I have a Named Client with the `DefaultRequestHeaders` being added at configuration level like so:

```
services.AddTransient<ValidateHeaderHandler>();
services.AddHttpClient("WeatherService", client =>
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:abcde/");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", GetNewAccessToken());
})
    .AddPolicyHandler(retryPolicy)
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<ValidateHeaderHandler>();
```

Added to the client is a `DelegatingHandler`. As I step through the override in `ValidateHeaderHandler`, which inherits from `DelegatingHandler`:

```
protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
    HttpRequestMessage request,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    if (!request.Headers.Contains("Authorization"))
    { ... }
    return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
}
```

The header will contain `"Authorization"` only on the first attempt of `base.SendAsync()`. After that execution, if Polly's retry policy is triggered, the `ValidateHeaderHandler`'s override of `SendAsync` will execute again - as expected - but all header information is completely gone.

Comment: Could you please shared with us the definition of `retryPolicy`? I could not reproduce your issue. For me the `BaseAddress` and `Headers` are always present during each retry attempt.